# Can't properly link libraries when compiling with Waf

Tags: c++, build, linker, shared-libraries, waf

I'm trying to compile a program that depends on [Caffe](http://caffe.berkeleyvision.org/) using [Waf](https://code.google.com/p/waf/source/checkout?repo=docs) (not my program, just trying to build it). During linking, I was getting the error

`/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lcaffe`

So I added the path to `libcaffe.so` to `obj.libpath` in `wscript` and it compiled. Yet when I run the compiled binary, I get an error telling me it can't find `libcaffe.so`. How is it possible that linking succeeds, yet the binary can't find the library?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How is it possible that linking succeeds, yet the binary can't find the library?

Linking with `/usr/bin/ld` is what's known as static linking (not to be confused with fully-static linking, achieved by using `-static` flag).

When your libraries are *installed* in a standard place on the system (e.g. in `/usr/lib`), everything just works. When you do *not* install `libcaffe.so` in a standard place, you need to know (more of) what you are doing.

You can direct the static linker to search additional directories for libraries, using the `-L /path/to/dir` linker flag. This allows you to achieve a successful static link, and gets you ready to the next step...

... which is called runtime loading. Runtime loading is performed by a completely different program (e.g. `/lib/ld-linux.so.2` on Linux).

The runtime loader again would have no problem loading your program and `libcaffe.so` if the latter is installed in a standard location. But when it is not installed in a standard location, the loader needs to be told where to find `libcaffe.so`. There are several system-specific methods for doing so.

Many UNIX runtime loaders pay attention to `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable.

It may be possible to compile `DT_RUNPATH` or `DT_RPATH` into the program itself, with e.g. `-Wl,-rpath=/path/to/dir` or similar static linker argument.

On some systems, it is possible to modify the "system" locations (which  are searched by default) by editing `/etc/ld.so.conf` or `/etc/ld.so.conf.d/...` files.